# Translating strings character by character

Tags: java, string

How should I go about implementing a method that gets a String composed of Latin characters to translate it into a String composed of a different set of characters, let's say Cyrillic.

Here's how it's done in PHP for example:

```
function latin_to_cyrillic($string)
{
 $array = array(
  "а" => "a",
  "б" => "b",
  "в" => "v",
  "г" => "g",
  "д" => "d",
  "е" => "e",
  "ж" => "zh",
  "з" => "z",
  "и" => "i",
  "й" => "y",
  "к" => "k",
  "л" => "l",
  "м" => "m",
  "н" => "n",
  "о" => "o",
  "п" => "p",
  "р" => "r",
  "с" => "s",
  "т" => "t",
  "у" => "u",
  "ф" => "f",
  "х" => "h",
  "ц" => "ts",
  "ч" => "ch",
  "ш" => "sh",
  "щ" => "sht",
  "ь" => "y",
  "ъ" => "a",
  "ю" => "yu",
  "я" => "ya",
  "А" => "A",
  "Б" => "B",
  "В" => "V",
  "Г" => "G",
  "Д" => "D",
  "Е" => "E",
  "Ж" => "Zh",
  "З" => "Z",
  "И" => "I",
  "Й" => "Y",
  "К" => "K",
  "Л" => "L",
  "М" => "M",
  "Н" => "N",
  "О" => "O",
  "П" => "P",
  "Р" => "R",
  "С" => "S",
  "Т" => "T",
  "У" => "U",
  "Ф" => "F",
  "Х" => "H",
  "Ц" => "Ts",
  "Ч" => "Ch",
  "Ш" => "Sh",
  "Щ" => "Sht",
  "Ь" => "Y",
  "Ъ" => "A",
  "Ю" => "Yu",
  "Я" => "Ya",
  "–" => "-");

 return str_replace(array_values($array), array_keys($array), $string);

}
```

Comment: Your question is ill-specified.  The terms "Latin characters" and "Cyrillic characters" are ill-specified: there exist many different "Latin" and "Cyrillic" character sets.  If you're thinking of something specific, such as two specific Windows character sets, please say so in your question.  In Java, Strings use Unicode, not any such character sets, so the question as formulated doesn't make sense, and you are probably going to need transliterations from/to such character sets and Unicode.

Comment: @reinierpost The OP uses the PHP example to specify the Latin and Cyrillic characters that he is interested in 'translating'

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need a conversion table, defining the translation for every character.

Then you read the string char by char, and use the translation table to get the translation. Easy, right?

you can use something like this:

```
class Translator {
 HashMap<String,String> translation = new HashMap<String,String>();

 public Translator(){
  //Populate the translation table here;
 }

 public String translate(String origin){
  String destiny="";
  for(int i=0;i<origin.length();i++){
   char character = origin.charAt(i);
   destiny = destiny + translation.get(Character.toString(character));
  }
 return destiny;
 }
}
```

Alternatively you could use

```
replaceEach(String text, String[] searchList, String[] replacementList) 
           Replaces all occurrences of Strings within another String.
```

From `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` .
You could populate a `String[]` with the latin characters (but as `String`), then populate another `String[]` with the cyrillic characters as `String`, and use that function.

```
String[] latinCharacters = [] //Populate them
String[] cyrillicCharacters = [] //Populate them

public String translate(String origin){
return replaceEach(origin,latinCharacters,cyrillicCharacters);
}
```

Comment: There is no Java class named HashTable, only HashMap and an obsolete Hashtable. And none of these can be parametrized with the primitive char. Correct that, please.

Comment: Does not pass the smell test.  `Hashtable` should be avoided in almost all circumstances, and instead `HashMap` used.  You cannot use primitive types for generics.  `destiny` is almost certain to run into `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The question involves possibly mapping a character to multiple characters.

Comment: Fixed according to @Michael comments. I did it by heart so he can get the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Also, avoid using string concatenation (`str = str + something`) in a loop. Instead, use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy variant: You call translateNameRusToEn method with your string

```
public class TranslateCharactersUtil {

public static final Map<Character, String> alphabetCharacters = new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
    put('а', "a"); put('б', "b"); put('в', "v"); put('г', "g"); put('д', "d");
    put('е', "e"); put('э', "e"); put('ё', "yo"); put('ж', "zh"); put('з', "z");
    put('и', "i"); put('й', "j"); put('к', "k"); put('л', "l"); put('м', "m");
    put('н', "n"); put('о', "o"); put('п', "p"); put('р', "r"); put('с', "s");
    put('т', "t"); put('у', "u"); put('ф', "f"); put('х', "h"); put('ц', "ts");
    put('ч', "ch"); put('ш', "sh"); put('щ', "sch"); put('ь', ""); put('ъ', "");
    put('ы', "y"); put('ю', "yu");put('я', "ya"); put(' ', "-"); put('.', "");
    put(',', "");
}};


public String translateNameRusToEn(String name) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (char symbol : chars) {
      char[] newSymbols = getFromMap(symbol);
        for (char newSymbol : newSymbols) {
            stringBuilder.append(newSymbol);
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private char[] getFromMap(char symbol) {
   return alphabetCharacters.getOrDefault(symbol, "?").toCharArray();
}
```

}