# java startsWith() method with custom rules

Tags: java, string, startswith

I implement typing trainer and would like to create my special String `startsWith()` method with specific rules.
For example: `'-'` char should be equal to any long hyphen (`'‒'`, etc). Also I'll add other rules for special accent characters (e equals **é**, but not **é** equals e).

```
public class TestCustomStartsWith {
    private static Map<Character, List<Character>> identityMap = new HashMap<>();
    static { // different hyphens: ‒, –, —, ―
        List<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add('‒');
        list.add('–'); // etc
        identityMap.put('-', list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(startsWith("‒d--", "-"));
    }

    public static boolean startsWith(String s, String prefix) {
        if (s.startsWith(prefix)) return true;
        if (prefix.length() > s.length()) return false;
        int i = prefix.length();
        while (--i >= 0) {
            if (prefix.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i)) {
                List<Character> list = identityMap.get(prefix.charAt(i));
                if ((list == null) || (!list.contains(s.charAt(i)))) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I could just replace all kinds of long hyphens with `'-'` char, but if there will be more rules, I'm afraid replacing will be too slow.

---

How can I improve this algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051595/translating-strings-character-by-character, but note that the only answer to that question got negative feedback.

Comment: "I'm afraid replacing will be too slow."  What's that they say about [premature optimizations being the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)?  I would go with the simplest thing for now (which sounds like it's to just replace the characters), and optimize it later _if_ profiling determines that it's a significant cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know all of your custom rules, but would a regular expression work?

The user is passing in a String.  Create a method to convert that String to a regex, e.g.

1. replace a short hyphen with short or long ([-‒]),
2. same for your accents, e becomes [eé]
3. Prepend with the start of word dohicky (\b),

Then convert this to a regex and give it a go.

Note that the list of replacements could be kept in a Map as suggested by Tobbias.  Your code could be something like

```
public boolean myStartsWith(String testString, String startsWith) {

    for (Map.Entry<String,String> me : fancyTransformMap) {
       startsWith = startsWith.replaceAll(me.getKey(), me.getValue());
    }

    return testString.matches('\b' + startsWith);
}
```

p.s. I'm not a regex super-guru so if there may be possible improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think something like a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that maps the undesirable characters to what you want them to be interpreted as might be the way to go if you are worried about performance;

```
HashMap<Character, Character> fastMap = new Map<Character, Character>();

// read it as '<long hyphen> can be interpreted as <regular-hyphen>
fastMap.add('–', '-');
fastMap.add('é', 'e');
fastMap.add('è', 'e');
fastMap.add('？', '?');
...
// and so on
```

That way you could ask for the value of the key: `value = map.get(key)`.

- However, this will only work as long as you have unique key-values. The caveat is that **é** can't be interpreted as **è** with this method - all the keys *must be unique*. However, if you are worried about performance, this is an exceedingly fast way of doing it, since the lookup time for a HashMap is pretty close to being O(1). But as others on this page has written, premature optimization is often a bad idea - try implementing something that works first, and if at the end of it you find it is too slow, *then* optimize.