# Replace series of characters with another series, respectively

Tags: java, regex, optimization, replaceall, character-replacement

I wish to replace a series of characters such `{a,b,...,x}` with another series such `{α,β,...,ω}`, *respectively* and *character-by-character* (means `a` with `α`, `b` with `β`, ... ,`x` with `ω`), by use of **Java**.

So I used this code and it works correctly:

```java
destSting = srcString
    .replaceAll("a","α")
    .replaceAll("b","β")
    // ...
    .replaceAll("x","ω");
```

Is there a better way (e.g. by use of `regex`)? Also I attend to *performance*.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051595/translating-strings-character-by-character#3051626

Comment: This is not a job for a regex.

Comment: You have a problem. You think "I know, I'll use a regex". Now you have two problems.

Comment: @JimGarrison; No. I don't think that. I said "**e.g.** by use of `regex`". I am just looking for a better way if there is.

Comment: Try [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replaceChars()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/index.html)

Comment: Basically what you want is what the *nix util `tr` does. I think the Java equal is `StringUtils.replaceChars`

Comment: @JimGarrison. Thanks. It works correctly. But I don't know its performance.

Comment: @JimGarrison If you’re going to cite that quote, you should include [proper attribution](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).