# How to parse number from string which uses unicode digits

Tags: java, regex, parsing, unicode

I'm trying to extract day number from string via regular expression

```
(?<!\d)([0123]?\d) september
```

But there are some strings which gives `NumberFormatException` when I try to parse result of regexp.
Example of one of such string:

```
private static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)([0123]?\\d) september", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringWithNumber = "  september";
    Matcher matcher = NUMBER.matcher(stringWithNumber);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String number = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("It's number: " + Integer.parseInt(number));
    }
}
```

Are there any Java API besides Integer.parseInt which can handle Unicode digits?

Of course, I can manually create class which uses HashMap like proposed here [Translating strings character by character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051595/translating-strings-character-by-character) but it looks like too much overhead and manual work for such simple task as parsing number. I think there are exist ready-to-use solution in java library.

Comment: Remove `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` if you do not want to match any Unicode digits but ASCII only. Or do you mean you want to replace `` with `2` etc. in the result and then parse?

Comment: The question is almost completely wrong. The regex is not the problem, the match succeeded. –– You want the numeric value of Unicode digits instead. Examples: [Perl](http://p3rl.org/Unicode::UCD#num()), [PHP](http://php.net/intlchar.getnumericvalue), [Node](https://npmjs.com/package/unicode-properties#getnumericvaluecodepoint)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. I would like to receive actual value `22`. Moreover this is just part of big complex regexp which need `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` to properly work.

Comment: @daxim where I said that regex is problem?) I mean, question explicitly states that I want to parse number.

Comment: Then delete the irrelevant part. You could simply say "I have  in a string, how do I get the numeric value 22?"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please explain why you marked this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3051595/272742 ? I think it's 2 different questions.

Comment: @daxim I've added background info to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). May be there are better solution to my task and I just don't know obvious alternative solution where I don't need to manually parse numbers at all.

Comment: Because that is what you ask for: how to replace `` with `2`, etc.

Comment: I have big number of symbols, not only ``. `` is just one example. There are a lot of symbols which in Unicode marked as ciphers. I want to be able to parse them all.