# Replacing multiple characters in Java with other multiple characters?

Tags: java, string

I've seen that there's some similar questions to this one, but answers there didn't really help me.
Anyways, I have a string like this "Today is Saturday". I need to change every char 'a' to 'b' and every char 'o' to 'f'. Basically, replacing multiple characters with multiple characters. Now, I've tried doing something like this:

```
String string.replace("a","b").replace("o","f");
```

But it only does the first replacement. I've tried using Stringbuilder:

```
stringBuilder.append(string);
for (int i=0; i<stringBuilder.length(); i++){
    char c=stringBuilder.charAt(i);
    if (c=='a'){
        I don't know how to replace it here to 'b'...
    }
}

stringBuilder.toString();
```

I've read I could use maps but I've never used them before and don't know how to do it. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: The chained `replace` calls do work, show us exactly how you were using them.

Comment: When I run this line of code: `System.out.println("Today is Saturday".replace('a', 'b').replace('o', 'f'));` the output I get is `Tfdby is Sbturdby` Where is the problem? Is that not the output you want? Also, class `StringBuilder` has method [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translating strings character by character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051595/translating-strings-character-by-character)

Comment: This was just an example code. It doesn't work in different examples because replace iterates through the whole string multiple times. What I'd like to do is use maps to replace characters, but I don't know how could I do that.

Comment: Muhannad, thank you. I will check that, seems pretty close to what I want.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Muhannad, but I'd like to use maps for this because it seems more elegant

Comment: Maps seem too expensive for this problem

Comment: Can you replace with String builder?

Comment: I've managed to do it with String builder. Would using replace be consider hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a method similar to the SQL `TRANSLATE` function.

```java
public static String translate(String input, String fromChars, String toChars) {
    if (fromChars.isEmpty() || fromChars.length() != toChars.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty())
        return input;
    char[] buf = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        char ch = buf[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < fromChars.length(); j++) {
            if (fromChars.charAt(j) == ch) {
                buf[i] = toChars.charAt(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(translate("Today is Saturday", "ao", "bf"));
```

*Output*

```
Tfdby is Sbturdby
```

---

Here is a version using `Map`, which supports Unicode characters from the Supplemental Planes, e.g. Emojis:

```java
public static String translate(String input, String fromChars, String toChars) {
    // Build codepoint mapping table
    if (fromChars.isEmpty() || fromChars.length() < toChars.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromChars cannot be shorter than toChars (" +
                fromChars.length() + " < " + toChars.length() + ")");
    }
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int fromIdx = 0, fromEnd, toIdx = 0; fromIdx < fromChars.length(); fromIdx = fromEnd) {
        fromEnd = fromChars.offsetByCodePoints(fromIdx, 1);
        String mapped = "";
        if (toIdx < toChars.length()) {
            int toEnd = toChars.offsetByCodePoints(toIdx, 1);
            mapped = toChars.substring(toIdx, toEnd);
            toIdx = toEnd;
        }
        if (map.put(fromChars.codePointAt(fromIdx), mapped) != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate value in fromChars at index " + fromIdx + ": " +
                                               fromChars.substring(fromIdx, fromEnd));
        }
    }

    // Map codepoints
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty())
        return input;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int idx = 0, end; idx < input.length(); idx = end) {
        end = input.offsetByCodePoints(idx, 1);
        String mapped = map.get(input.codePointAt(idx));
        buf.append(mapped != null ? mapped : input.substring(idx, end));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(translate("Today is Saturday ", "aor", "bf"));
```

*Output*

```
Tfdby is Sbtudby
```

Notice how the `r` is removed, because `toChars` is shorter than `fromChars`. This is how the SQL `TRANSLATE` function works.